# change user to sudo(root) after login to other server

Tags: linux, sudo, root, sftp, tomcat

i have 2 servers(Linux 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64) suppose fe1 and fe2.

i need to run a command (*service tomcat start/stop*) on fe2 from fe1 but it requires **sudo as root**.
Command that i am using for **sudo root is *`sudo su`***

```
#!/bin/sh
host=fe2
user=`whoami`
sftp $user@fe2 << EOF
sudo su
service tomcat stop
bye
EOF
```

can it be done in some other way?

Comment: sftp, really? Not ssh?

Answer (score 1):

You can send any commnd over ssh from fe1 to fe2 as follows

```
ssh whoami@fe2 'sudo service tomcat start'
```

If you want to run multiple command over `ssh` from one seever to other seperate commands with `;` inside th`' '` as follows

```
ssh whoami@fe2 'sudo -s; service tomcat start; service tomcat status; other_commands; '
```

`ssh` will run all of them in the order you've mentioned. Any `stdin` request will be taken from commanding server and any output at `stdout` or `stderror` will also be transferred over `ssh`